# Django URL Routing misbehaving, routing to an unanticipated path

Tags: python, django, post, http-post

I made some changes to model.py, foreignKey adjustments. (I realized I placed them on the wrong class). Deleted the database and created a new from scratch since I was that far in. When I felt like i corrected everything in the DB to run, and ran runserver again, i get an KeyError error, to a path it shouldn't be directed to.

When I type in the url 127.0.0.1:8000/add_tech/, or add_exp/ it loads the right form, when I submit, it shows it the function received the term **tech** or **exp** through the regex in urls.py, but disappointingly the stack trace output shows differently.

The views.py doesn't seem to routing correctly. Are there steps I should follow to help step through and debug this?

urls.py has the following

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from resume.views import add_entry, remove_entry

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^add_(\w+)/$',add_entry),
    url(r'^remove_(\w+)/$',remove_entry),
)
```

It's being routed to views.py in resume/: (As seen)

```
def add_entry(request, option):
print "Print Option in Url is:"+option #<----- see console out below.
options={
    'job':add_job(request),
    'exp':add_exp(request),
    'tech':add_tech(request),
    'course':add_course(request),
    'project':add_project(request)
    }
form_html = options[option]    
return form_html
```

This is what the print displays in console, it should be routed to add_exp, not sure how it's being routed to add_tech, as you see when an error is raised.:

```
[18/May/2014 17:01:21] "GET /add_exp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1446

Print Option in Url is:**exp**

Internal Server Error: **/add_exp/**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, \*\*callback_kwargs)

File "/home/asilvajr/Repository/mysite/resume/views.py", line 120, in **add_entry**
    'tech':add_tech(request),

File "/home/asilvajr/Repository/mysite/resume/views.py", line 19, in **add_tech**
    return submit_tech(request)

File "/home/asilvajr/Repository/mysite/resume/views.py", line 76, in **submit_tech**
    if vals['tech_name']:

KeyError: 'tech_name'

---- End Console Output -----
```

Just the form, in tech_form (should be loaded before and after submit):

```
<form action="/add_tech/" method="POST">
<label for="Tech">Technolgy Used:</label>
    <input type="text" name="tech_name"><br/>
    <label for="Type">Type:</label>
<select name="tech_type">
    <option name="L">Language</option>
    <option name="Fr">Framework</option>
    <option name="T">Tools</option>
    <option name="K">Kits</option>
    <option name="E">Extensions</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"><br/>
</form>
```

Just the form, in exp_form (should be loaded before and after submit):

```
<form action="/add_exp/" method="POST">
<label for="Event">Event:</label>
    <input type="text" name="event"><br/>
    <label for="Description">Description:</label>
<textarea type="textarea" name="exp_descript"></textarea><br/>
<label for="Technology">Technology Used:</label>
{% for tech in techs %}
<input type="checkbox" class="tech_{{ tech.tech_type }}" name="technologies" value="{{ tech.id }}">{{ tech.name }} :: {{ tech.tech_type }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="submit"><br/>
</form>
```

Both add_tech and add_exp are designed like so:

```
def add_tech(request):
    if 'submit' in request.POST:
        return submit_tech(request)
    techs = Technologies.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tech_form.html',{'techs':techs})
```

Submit_tech as requested:

```
def submit_tech(request):
    vals = request.POST.dict()
    vals['errors']=[]
    if vals['tech_name']:
        try:
            exists=Technologies.objects.get(name=vals['tech_name'])
        except Technologies.DoesNotExist:
            exists=None
        if not exists:
            tech = Technologies(name=vals['tech_name'],tech_type=vals['tech_type'])
            tech.save()
        else:
            vals['errors'].append(exists.name + "already exists as a " + exists.tech_type)
    else:
        vals['errors'].append("Added Nothing, Text Feild was empty")
    vals['techs'] = Technologies.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tech_form.html', vals)
```

Comment: The error seems happen inside `submit_tech` function. Could you also paste that function here?

Comment: Added Submit_tech as requested @ZZY , i'm looking it over, but it looks fine. Just not sure I'm understanding why it's being routed to (anything)_tech when the page should be focused (anything)_exp,or vice-versa. Templates wouldn't match the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test project and copy paste your codes. It works fine here, I can successfully POST to `/add_tech/`, and a new `Technologies` was created in DB.

I suggest you to check the `render()` statement in your `add_exp` function, is the template name correct?

Additionally, two suggestions:
1). in `add_entry` funciton, add handling for invalid entry name; 2). in 3rd line of `submit_tech` function, use `if vals.get('tech_name', None):`, otherwise the codes will raise 500 error when somebody submit an invalid form

Comment: It's an odd behavior, glad to hear you were able to make it work though @ZZY. I can comment a row out in the options dict shown above, and the add_entry function would then direct add_tech(), as it should. Changing the key or moving where 'exp':add_exp() is in the dict, still has it redirect to itself. I'm working around it for now through urls.py. 
Thank you for the suggestions, that actually resolved another issue that I thought was a related issue. I'm hoping as I work on, I'll wash it out.